# Get DataGrid header for a given control

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

You are given: A reference to a UI control (e.g. a TextBox) located inside an [ASP.NET DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx).

Your task: Find the header of the DataGrid column.

---

I found the following solution, but I don't particularly like it, because (a) it is complicated and (b) it (ab)uses knowledge about the HTML representation of the DataGrid:

1. Starting from the UI control (`ctl`), traverse up the `Parent` property until reaching the TableCell (`tc`) and its parent DataGridItem (`dgi`).
2. Get the index (`index`) of the TableCell in the DataGrid's `Cells` property (`dgi.Cells.Cast<TableCell>().ToList().IndexOf(tc)`).
3. Traverse further up the `Parent` property until reaching the DataGrid (`grid`), then access the header text using this index: `grid.Columns(index).HeaderText`.

I'm sure that there is a more elegant solution to this problem. What is it?

Comment: `DataGrid` or `GridView`? In general there is no relation between your textbox and the header so there is no more elegant way.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: DataGrid. I am aware that GridView is the more modern alternative, but this is a legacy project.

Comment: That's already the best, there is no elegant way. If that's a legacy project, can use use LINQ at all?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I see. Yes, LINQ can be used, and I've already implemented the solution mentioned in the question. Feel free to make your comment an answer and I'll accept it, so that the question can be "closed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGrid` or `GridView`? In general there is no relation between your `TextBox` and the header so there is no really elegant way.

This is the best i've come up with but i doubt that it's more elegant than your approach:

`GridView`:

```
protected void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)txt.NamingContainer;
    GridView grid = (GridView)row.NamingContainer;
    DataControlField column = grid.Columns.Cast<DataControlField>()
        .Select((c, Index) => new { Column = c, Index })
        .Where(x => row.Cells[x.Index].GetControlsRecursively().Contains(txt))
        .Select(x => x.Column)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (column != null)
    {
        string headerText = column.HeaderText;
    }
}
```

`DataGrid`:

```
protected void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
    DataGridItem item = (DataGridItem)txt.NamingContainer;
    DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)item.NamingContainer;
    DataControlField column = grid.Columns.Cast<DataControlField>()
        .Select((c, Index) => new { Column = c, Index })
        .Where(x => item.Cells[x.Index].GetControlsRecursively().Contains(txt))
        .Select(x => x.Column)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (column != null)
    {
        string headerText = column.HeaderText;
    }
}
```

I'm using this extension method to find controls recursively:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetControlsRecursively(this Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        yield return c;

        if (c.HasControls())
        {
            foreach (Control control in c.GetControlsRecursively())
            {
                yield return control;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This approach uses the `gridView.Columns` collection as source since you want to find find the column. It needs to find the `TextBox` via the `GridViewRow`/`DataGridItem` and a recursive search in each cell of this item/row. If the reference to the `TextBox` is found the header is found.

Note that you can't use `item.Cells[x.Index].FindControl(txt.ID)` since `FindControl` first tries to find the `NamingContainer` of the control which is the `GridViewRow`/`DataGridItem` so it doesn't help to search the cells.